# background image too large and out of focus

Tags: html, background

This is my code

```
<style type="text/css">
        body {
           background-size:cover;
           background-image:url('Orange.jpg');
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-attachment: fixed;
           background-size: 100% auto;
        }


    </style>
```

The background image is way too large, zoomed in, and out of focus
Please help

Thanks, Duncan

Comment: When you use background-size: cover, it will stretch the image to fill your body. Depending on the resolution of your image, it could look very blurry if it is too big. Considering that the most common screen resolution is 1366 x 768, you will want to make sure your image is at least that big (probably bigger)

Answer (score 0):

That's normal when you resize an image to be bigger, the image will be out of focus and zoomed in(that's how it works).
If you don't want to lose quality, you need to get an image bigger than the last one.